# How to write client for jabberd14 server

Tags: client, chat, xmpp

Anyone can tell me how to kick start development a super simple client for jabberd14 server? I am comfortable using C++, VB .NET, PHP (for webdevelopment).

And also how to add user in the server itself (any API to do this) like mysql has develop a connector to pass the sql statement to the server to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to write something from scratch, you should start getting familiar with the [XMPP Protocol](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/) used by Jabber.

However, it might be better to use an existing [XMPP/Jabber library](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) which does the dirty work for you.

Comment: Thanks. Any way/API to administer server like create user?

Answer (score 0):

For **.net** check the project [jabber-net on Google code.](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/)
And here's a [getting started guide](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/wiki/GettingStarted).

For **Java SE** have a look at this API: [Smack API](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/).
And the [getting started guide](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/gettingstarted.html).